# Error with listings and baposter

Tags: listings, baposter

I want to include listings in my baposter poster but I get the following error if I do:

```
! Paragraph ended before \lst@next was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.288   }
```

How can I include listings without getting an error?

An Example:

```
\documentclass[portrait,final,a0paper]{baposter}
\usepackage{listings}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{poster}{}{}
\textsc{}


\headerbox{Problem}{name=problem,column=0,row=0}{
\iffalse
\begin{lstlisting}                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Test
\end{lstlisting}
\fi                                                                                                                                                                                                                
}

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

As soon as I remove the \iffalse and \fi, it stops compiling.

Edit: Made the example an MWE.

Comment: listings as with all verbatim like constructions cannot be used in the argument to a command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Listings` works fine in `posterbox` environments. `posterbox` replaced `headerbox` to permit use of `verbatim` environments.

Here is a MWE and its output.

```
\documentclass[landscape,a0paper]{baposter}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
  basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
  language=[LaTeX]{TeX}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{poster}{
  grid=false,
  columns=2,
  colspacing=4.2mm,
  headerheight=0.07\textheight,
  background=none,
  eyecatcher=false,
  %posterbox options
  headerborder=closed,
  borderColor=red,
  headershape=rectangle,
  headershade=plain,
  headerColorOne=blue,
  textborder=rectangle,
  boxshade=plain,
  boxColorOne=white,
  headerFontColor=white,
  headerfont=\color{white}\large\bfseries\sffamily,
  textfont=\normalsize\sffamily,
  linewidth=1pt
}
{} % Left / top logo
{Title}
{\textsc{Author}}
{} % Right logo

\begin{posterbox}[name=box1,column=0,column=0,row=0,span=1]{Title}

\lstinputlisting{\jobname.tex}

\end{posterbox}

\begin{posterbox}[name=box1,column=0,column=1,row=0,span=1]{Title}

\begin{lstlisting}
\documentclass[landscape,a0paper]{baposter}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  language=[LaTeX]{TeX}
}

\begin{document}


\end{document}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{posterbox}

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I completed the MWE, there seems to be no missing closing brace.

Comment: Ah, I need to use posterbox instead of headerbox, that fixed it, thanks!

Comment: `Posterbox` replaced `headerbox` to permit use of verbatim environments.